# compare 2 csv files and find unmatched filepaths and output into absolute path with their length?

Tags: powershell

[image]

this is one csv file with relativepath. similarly I have 2 csv files with relative paths . I had tried to compare both csv files and find unmatched filepaths wit absolutepath and length but I did not get the proper output . Can anyone help me on this?and output like below?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC7oG.png)

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide sample data in text form, what output you expect, and what you've tried so far and where, specifically, you're stuck.

Comment: I want output in absolutepath and length from that relativepaths csv files

Comment: Please follow the guidance in my previous comment, and I suggest you also read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If those paths are all relative to the present working directory where the script is running then you could use Get-ChildItem with each relative path. You can pull the full file path and name from the results of Get-ChildItem. You would have to do additional steps to get the info for just the files you want.